# Cannot convert Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core-mvc, webapi, newtons-method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SiparisEkle(int userID, [FromQuery] int[] productIDs, [FromQuery] short[] quantities)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userID, productIDs, quantities), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        using (var cevap = await httpClient.PutAsync($"{uri}/api/Order/SiparisEkle", content))
        {
            string apiCevap = await cevap.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

How can I go about fixing this error?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SiparisEkle(int userID, [FromQuery] int[] productIDs, [FromQuery] short[] quantities)
{
    Order newOrder = new Order();
    newOrder.UserID = userID;
    newOrder.Status = Status.Pending;
    newOrder.isActive = true;


    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newOrder), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        using (var cevap = await httpClient.PutAsync($"{uri}/api/Order/SiparisEkle", content))
        {
            string apiCevap = await cevap.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

This is how it is last. This is how I solved my problem

Comment: Fixing *what* error? What are you trying to do, and *exactly* what error are you facing, and on which line?

Comment: StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userID, productIDs, quantities), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");  This line

Comment: So *edit the question* to explain that, as well as giving the *full* error message. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for guidance on how to write a good question.

Comment: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int[]' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter'

Comment: Again, *edit the question*. All of this information should be *in the question*, not just in comments.

Comment: But fundamentally, you're passing three arguments to `SerializeObject` - how do you expect those three objects to be used? Have you looked at the overloads of `SerializeObject`? Which do you expect to be applied?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried instantiating the 'content' object on a separate line and then trying to set it, like so:

```
StringContent content = new StringContent();
content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userID, productIDs, quantities);
```

Apologies if that's an unhelpful suggestion. I cannot see the StringContent class so I do not know if you need it in one due to a constructor in the class. For more help, here is the NewtonSoft documentation about Serializing and Deserializing. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm#JsonSerializer

Comment: No, that won't help, because the problem is the call to `SerializeObject` - and if that worked, it would return a `string`, which can't be assigned to a variable of type `StringContent`.